# How to compile code in runtime

Tags: java, android, compilation, runtime

I want to use some views ID's, and I want a loop to iterate through all of them.
Here's what I mean:

```
for (int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt+i);
}
```

Of course it is wrong, but lets say I have in the layout 10 `TextViews`:

```
txt0

txt1

txt2

.

.

.

txt9
```

I want the loop to perform something like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt0);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
.
.
.
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt+9);
```

Is it possible??

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the ID by name like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
     int id = getResources().getIdentifier("txt" + i, "id", context.getPackageName());
     TextView tv = findViewById(id);
     // but what here?
}
```

However, this just assigns a textview 10 times.  What are you doing after this?  I can't see how this is useful but perhaps you can build on it.

Comment: Thanks! that exactly what I needed. I'm trying to design a widget, and you have to get to each `TextView` with it's ID. After this, I set the text of every `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

Instead try this

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
```

and set tag as for loop index and access it by tag

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
TextView[] tv=new TextView[10];
for (int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
    tv[i] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt+i);
 tv[i].setId(1000+i);

}
```

when you want use a textview. use tv[1] ...etc

Comment: Wont work. The operation R.id.txt+i happens at runtime where as the right reference needs to be set at compile time

Comment: You cannot just increment the id.  There is no correlation between the id and the referenced resource.

Comment: Actually, this *will* probably work, as the view ID constants assigned at compile time tend to be sequential.  But it would be bad practice to rely on that.

Comment: if you want set id for textview. use 
 TextView[] tv=new TextView[10];
    for (int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
        tv[i] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt+i);
        tv[i].setId(1000+i); //id will not dumlicate

    }

Comment: @NguyễnAnhQuế  It only worked by coincidence, because the textviews are listed in order in the XML but this is not guaranteed and simply rearranging the XML will break existing code.  Google might also change the algorithm to generate the IDs and again, existing code will break.  This is not documented and is plain and simply the wrong way to do it.  Please don't keep pushing it as a solution because it is wrong.